# Rust backpointers

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust from a C++/Java background, and I have the following pattern

```rust
struct Node<'a> {
    network_manager: NetworkManager<'a>,
}

struct NetworkManager<'a> {
    base_node: &'a Node<'a>,
}
```

The node contains the threadpool that the `NetworkManager` uses to "handoff" messages once they've been processed. Because of the recursive call, it is not possible to set the base_node field in the `NetworkManager` immediately. In Java, I would leave it as null and have a second method that is called after the constructor called `initialise(BaseNode node)` that would set the `base_node` field (ensuring that there are no calls to the network manager before `initialise` is called).

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Rust? The only way I can think of is to make `base_node` an `Option` type, but this seems suboptimal.

In general, what is the "right" way in Rust to deal with situations where A points to B and B points to A, and where (as in my case), refactoring is not possible?

Comment: Another nitpick: "make base_node an Option type, but this seems suboptimal" but that's what you were doing in Java and you though that was fine.

Comment: @mcarton: That will not work since there can only be one owner of a node - either the local variable accessing it or the network manager. Backpointers need more complex references, e.g. `Rc<RefCell<Node>>`.

Comment: I know, but he was still not making a fair comparison.

Comment: *refactoring is not possible* Uh, why not? You haven't shown any code that actually uses these types. What is *the recursive call*? There is no recursion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, these situations are very different from other languages. In "safe, simple, everyday Rust" having backpointers/pointers within the struct is complex since it leads to non-trivial problems. (Consider what would happen if you would move `Node` around in memory: How would you properly update the backpointer in `NetworkManager`?)

What I usually resort to is simply passing `base_node` as a parameter to the functions that need the backpointer. This is sometimes easier said than done, but leads to code that clearly states ownership.